# Return key on fuzzy match of element in dictionary list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this:

| Date | Cost Category | Vendor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-22 | - | FamilyMart |
| 2021-03-04 | - | FAMILY MART |
| 2021-03-14 | - | Subway MAIN |
| 2021-03-14 | - | OTHER |
| 2021-03-14 | - | Transit Authority |
| 2021-03-09 | - | Subway local |
| 2021-03-24 | - | Seven Eleven |
| 2021-03-14 | - | Seven-Eleven |

I want to add category tags like this:

| Date | Cost Category | Vendor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-22 | Store | FamilyMart |
| 2021-03-04 | Store | FAMILY MART |
| 2021-03-14 | Dining | Subway MAIN |
| 2021-03-14 | - | OTHER |
| 2021-03-14 | - | Transit Authority |
| 2021-03-09 | Dining | Subway local |
| 2021-03-24 | Store | Seven Eleven |
| 2021-03-14 | Store | Seven-Eleven |

I try the following, which would just return the value of the matching element in the list:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

Store = ['Family Mart', 'Seven Eleven', 'York Mart', 'Tokyu', 'Ministop']
Dining = ['Subway', 'Salad Works'] 

def fuzz_m(col, cat_list, score_t):
    tag, score = process.extractOne(col, cat_list, scorer = score_t)
    if score < 51:
        return ''
    else:
        return tag
    
df['Cost Category'] = df['Vendor'].apply(fuzz_m, cat_list = Store, score_t = fuzz.ratio)
```

| Date | Cost Category | Vendor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-22 | Family Mart | FamilyMart |
| 2021-03-04 | Family Mart | FAMILY MART |
| 2021-03-14 | - | Subway MAIN |
| 2021-03-14 | - | OTHER |
| 2021-03-14 | - | Transit Authority |
| 2021-03-09 | - | Subway local |
| 2021-03-24 | Seven Eleven | Seven Eleven |
| 2021-03-14 | Seven Eleven | Seven-Eleven |

What I want to do is use a dictionary in place of cat_list and return the key in Cost Category.

```
dictionary = {'Store':['Family Mart', 'Seven Eleven', 'York Mart', 'Tokyu', 'Ministop'],
                  'Dining':['Subway', 'Salad Works']
                 }
```

Where if any value in the column has a 51+ match to an element in a list, then I want to add the key under Cost Category. If it is a low match (below 51) I want to do nothing.

Is there a feasible approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [**`Series.apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), `fuzz_m()` receives one `Vendor` value at a time, so you can use that `dictionary` directly as `extractOne(value, dictionary)`:

```py
def fuzz_m(value):
    _, score, tag = process.extractOne(value, dictionary)
    return tag if score > 50 else '-'

df['Cost Category'] = df['Vendor'].apply(fuzz_m)

#          Date  Cost Category             Vendor
# 0  2021-03-22          Store         FamilyMart
# 1  2021-03-04          Store        FAMILY MART
# 2  2021-03-14         Dining        Subway MAIN
# 3  2021-03-14              -              OTHER
# 4  2021-03-14              -  Transit Authority
# 5  2021-03-09         Dining       Subway local
# 6  2021-03-24          Store       Seven Eleven
# 7  2021-03-14          Store       Seven-Eleven
```

Comment: Excellent and straightforward solution. Thank you